# Basic JavaScript alert not showing

Tags: javascript, asp.net, jquery, google-api, master-pages

I've got an `aspx` masterpage and want to include Google's jQuery script. However, to test it's working, I've got the below code in the head of my masterpage. However, none of the content pages display the alert. What am I missing?

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" />

 <script type="text/javascript">
   $(document).ready(function() {                
     alert("Test Alert");                
   });
 </script>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`<script>` tags are not self-closing.

**Replace**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js" />
```

**with**

```
 <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: So simple :/ thanks! (will have to accept answer in a few mins)

Comment: +1 - this will cause JavaScript errors on anything past it, even the syntax highlighter here knows it :)

Comment: Yeah @Nick I noticed that as well when I was writing my answer. Pretty cool.

Comment: @marko , how do you catch these type of things so fast..is it through your eyes or with some tool...which highlights..syntax issues

Comment: @gov, as @Nick had pointed out as well - the syntax highlighter picked up on it as well, see how the 2nd `<script type="text/javascript">` isn't the same as the first one? But usually I catch it by eye, years of practise helps :)